# Creating a PUT request in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameter-passing, put

I want to be able to use a PUT request to edit the title of a song I uploaded in my Ruby on Rails application.

```
def update
   @sound_byte = SoundByte.find(params[:id]) #Error here
   @sound_byte.update!(sound_byte_params)
   flash[:success] = "The soundbyte title was changed."
   redirect_to sound_byte_path
end

private

def sound_byte_params
    params.require(:sound_byte).permit(:mpeg, :mpeg_file_name)
end
```

I end up getting an error like this:

```
Couldn't find SoundByte with 'id'=song_name
```

Any ideas of how to fix this issue? I am using the Paperclip gem to enable the audio/mpeg file uploads.

EDIT: Here is my views code

```
<%= link_to "Edit", sound_byte_path(sound_byte.mpeg_file_name), class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-xlarge", :method => :put %>
```

Comment: There's something wrong with your params. Could you provide the form code?

Comment: @phamhoaivu sorry I am not quite sure what you mean by form code? I attached the code in my views that corresponds to the PUT request.

Comment: I thought you have to have a form to edit the song. Some text box to enter the new song's name and a button to submit.

Answer (score 1):

In the view page, you pass string `sound_byte.mpeg_file_name` as params, but in your controller, you use id `@sound_byte = SoundByte.find(params[:id])`.

Try this

```
<%= link_to "Edit", sound_byte_path(sound_byte.id), class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-xlarge", :method => :put %>
```

Comment: I am now getting an error that says: param is missing or the value is empty: sound_byte

The error is on this line:  params.require(:sound_byte).permit(:mpeg)

Do I need to do what phamhoaivu recommended and include a form to submit the new song name?

Comment: yes, you need to paste the form code and config/routers.rb. and if you can, you can also paste the console logs, show the params, handle controller and actions. The problem is that you pass some illegal data to your controller, the params[id] shouldn't equal to the name.